How do I turn Part's CanCollide off for only one player(specific player)?
When a player has a certain amount of something I wanna disable canCollide on a wall(part) but I don't know how to do it only for one player. Right now you click something and it adds to your "Clicks" in leaderstats, and when you have a certain amount of clicks, you get should be able to get access through the wall

You can do this using the Collision Service and creating collision groups. Note that these functions only work on the server side.

Does this answer your question? How to create a hitbox that lets players through if they have enough money and keeps them out when they don't have enough? - Roblox

You can run a check on the Touched event of a BasePart and check whether a player has enough clicks and if they do, then set CanCollide off.
In the below script, find how much clicks the player has in clicksStat and then if that player has enough clicks, which is stored in clicksNeeded, then wallPart's CanCollide is set to false.
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local player = Players.LocalPlayer
local wallPart = script.Parent -- Make this where your wall is

local leaderstats = player and player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")
local clicksStat = leaderstats and leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Clicks")

local clicksNeeded = 100 -- Clicks needed for CanCollide = false

-- Check every time wallPart is touched if the player has enough clicks
local function onTouched(otherPart)
    if player and clicksStat >= clicksNeeded then
        wallPart.CanCollide = false -- Disable collision if player has enough clicks
    end
end

wallPart.Touched:Connect(onTouched)

